# firestore get document with his children

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a users collection every user has a sub collection called "settings" and "settings" have documents like ids "option1","option2"

```
return this.fireStore.doc(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges()
```

so I need to get also a user settings with all documents options like

```
  userA =  {
    username:'name',
    email:'email@email',
    settings:{
    option1 :{data},
    option2 :{data}
  }}
```

Comment: Try return this.fireStore.doc(`users/${user.uid}/settings/option1`).valueChanges() or 
this.fireStore.collection(users).doc(${user.uid}).collection(settings) if want both options. Or you can put the settings together with the email in the same doc.

Comment: i did what you said but it's return settings collection without user details

Answer (score 3):

There is no API in Firestore to get documents from multiple collections in one go. You will have to use two separate calls: one for the main `user` document, and one for all documents in the `settings` subcollection.

Comment: thanks for your  help but you can give me an example

Comment: Note that Firestore now has [collection group queries](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) and some useful docs on [aggregating queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions).

Comment: Correct, although even with Collection Group Queries you can only query over collections of the same name and you will get documents from collection(s) with that name only. There is still no loading of a document with its subcollections.